# Load a new URL with appended JavaScript, then append more JS to that new URL

Tags: javascript, append, window.location

I have a bookmark that appends JavaScript to a page that causes the page to load another page (using window.location.assign(newURL)).

After that new URL is loaded, I then want to then interact with the elements on the new URL by appending another script.

Overall, I want to:

1. Click on a bookmark that pops up a prompt window asking for a search term
2. After inputting the search term, load the URL of a search page
3. Drop the search term into the search term input box of the search page. Note that the search is being done behind the scenes -- the URL does not change to reflect the search terms, like what you see with Google. (It's searching a list of users within a Plone site.)
4. Run the search

Is this possible? How?

I've tried setInterval, setTimeout, onreadystatechange, hashchange... But the problem is that when the new page gets loaded, the script previously attached to the original page is wiped out (which seems logical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have observed, when a script loads a new URL in the current window, all scripts in the current window are destroyed and thus cannot operate on the newly loaded window.

As such, you have these options:

1. Put the code to modify the newly loaded window into the startup sequence of the newly loaded page itself so that when that page loads, it runs the desired code on itself.
2. Pass some arguments to the newly loaded page as query parameters on the end of the URL and then use code in the newly loaded page to process those query parameters and implement whatever startup operation you want when the new page is loaded.  While the code to implement this startup operation must be in the newly loaded page (like in option 1), it still allows the code loading the page to specify what happens when it is loaded this time by attaching query parameters to the loaded URL.  So, if the URL you are loading is `http://whatever.com/foo.html`, then you can attach some query parameters to it like `http://whatever.com/foo.html?show=price&user=bob` and the startup script in that page can look at those query parameters and act accordingly.  This allows the loader of the URL to pass arguments to the startup code in the page.
3. Find some external window that can load the new URL in some other window (perhaps an iframe, but doesn't have to be an iframe), watch it load and when it finishes loading, run some code to modify it.  The two cooperating windows will have to be in the same domain (technically same origin) for Javascript to allow this.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply; I went with option 3, as it made the most sense in my context. I've been able to load the new page in an iframe, and I also append another JS file to that iframe document, and that JS file interacts with the page successfully. (I'm doing everything on the same domain, so don't get the cross-domain error.) Well, almost successfully -- now I'm just trying to update the value of the search box, but that problem seems easier to reach now that the basics are running.

Comment: @hellotumo - since it looks like you may be fairly new to StackOverflow, are you aware that when your question gets answered, you can click the green checkmark to the left of your preferred answer?  This indicates to the community that your question has been answered and earns both you and the person who supplied the answer some reputation points here on StackOverflow.  After you earn some more reputation points, you can then upvote (click the uparrow next to an answer) for each answer that helped you, not only the most helpful one.

Comment: Got it, thank you. For the record, to get to the <input> of the <form>, I did:

var getThatForm = document.forms["users_search_orYourIdForForm"];
var getThatSearchBox = getThatForm.elements[1];
var nameToFind = prompt('Name to hunt for?');
getThatSearchBox.value=nameToFind;
document.forms["users_search_orYourIdForForm"].submit();

Answer (score 0):

Sure, @bummi. Good point. Here are the .js files as described in the link.

**I. JS File 1**

You attach this to your document by creating a bookmark with the URL structured like so:

`javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='jsFile1.js';})();`

***The code of jsFile1.js:***

Make a variable that holds a new  element:

```
    var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
```

Choose the page you want to load onto ifrm:

```
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.monkeyseatkoalas.blahblah");
```

A bit of styling of the iframe:

```
    ifrm.style.width = 100+"%"; 
    ifrm.style.height = 600+"px";
```

Attach the new  to the body of the page we're on. Caveats: `<iframe>` and goofing about with it in this fashion only works when you keep everything in one domain. So if you're on XYZ site, the page you're loading in the iframe needs to be from XYZ site, too.

```
   document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

Now we have an iframe on our document. We know it has a position of [0] because we read [all about frames right here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames). So let's now do something odd -- let's attach another JavaScript file to this new iframe page. Why? Because that makes it easy to manipulate that page  with that fresh JS file. Here you go:

`frames[0].document.body.appendChild(frames[0].document.createElement('script')).src='jsFile2.js';`

***II. JS File 2***

We don't want to do anything until the whole beast is loaded. Otherwise, we might not be able to access somthing we want, or calculations we do based upon elements in the page might not work. Still, it's your call. You might be able to run this at an earlier stage in the load.

`window.onload = function () { // more code to come below...`

Looky there at that, ".forms" is a nice trick. w00t! Handy! In the brackets of *var **getDatForm***, we have the form's ID. If it doesn't have one, go ahead and give it one, and make your life easier. How? Hmm. I think...

`document.forms[numberOfFormElementOnThePage].setAttribute('id', 'mySpecialCupcakeFormCheeseName');`

To continue our line of thought, here we set *var **getDatForm***:

`var getDatForm = document.forms["IDofYourForm"];`

Well, we need to find and store the box we want to populate with something. So we just use our form, nicely stuck in a variable, and do that super-handy .elements[x] to it. In a form, this refers to the `<input>` tag. So the first `<input>` tag in your form will be yourForm.elements[0]. In my case, I needed yourForm.elements[1](http://hellotumo.com/2015/01/25/javascript-cms-tricks-search-user-database-from-anywhere-on-site/).

`var getDatSearchBox = getDatForm.elements[1];`

Gettin' all interactivey here. Yep, ask your friendly Web user to provide something he/she wants to find with prompt. Stick it in a variable.

`var nameToFind = prompt('Word to hunt for? Name? Ice cream? Doggy?');`

Update your search box (in the variable **getDatSearchBox**) with that text using value.

`getDatSearchBox.value=nameToFind;`

BOOM! Submit your form.

```
document.forms["users_search"].submit();

};
```